# Non-abelian representations and their induced abelian representations

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}\DeclareMathOperator\Out{Out}\newcommand\ab{^{\text{ab}}}$Let $G$ and $H$ be a groups and assume that $H$ is non-abelian. Then we have a morphism
$$\Out(H)\rightarrow \Aut(H\ab).$$
For example if $H=F_2$, the free group with two generators, this map is an isomorphism, for $F_n$ with $n\geq 3$ this is only a surjection and for more general groups this is not a surjection, as was pointed out in the comments by Will Sawin and Mark Wildon.

My question thus is if we are given a morphism $$\rho:G\rightarrow \Aut(H\ab)$$
does there exist a way to tell if this comes from a morphism
$$G\rightarrow \Out(H)?$$

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not a surjection in general. Why should it be?

Comment: The map $\mathrm{Out}(H) \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(H^{\mathrm{ab}})$ is not in general surjective. I had an incorrect example and I see Will Sawin has now posted a correct one.

Comment: @MarkWildon I don't think your example is the right one, because $H^{\mathrm{ab}} =C_2$. However, $C_5 \rtimes C_4$ works, because its abelianization $C_4$ has an automorphism, which does not lift to $C_5 \rtimes C_4$.

Comment: You are both absolutely right! We do have a surjection if $H$ is a free group however, which is what I had in mind. I'll change the question accordingly.

Comment: First, you should require that $\rho$ lands in the image of ${\rm Out}(H)$.

Comment: If yes, then you get a cohomology class in $$H^2(G,{\rm ker}[{\rm Out}(H)\to {\rm Aut}(H^{\rm ab})]).$$

Comment: You can lift $\rho$ if and only if the cohomology class is *neutral*.

Comment: There may be more than one neutral class in nonabelian $H^2$.

Comment: You can find a down-to-earth treatment of nonabelian $H^2$ in my paper :M. Borovoi, Abelianization of the second nonabelian Galois cohomology. Duke Math. J. 72 (1993), 217-239, and also in the references therein (especially in Springer's paper) and in papers referring to my paper and to Springer.